# Issue with adding a Mapinfo-File using BridjOGRDataStoreFactory in GeoTools

Tags: geotools

I am very new to Geotools, Maven, and all this Java Stuff.

I am trying to add `Mapinfo-File` using `BridjOGRDataStoreFactory` follow the instruction provided by you on link [OgrPlugin](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/ogr.html) by using the code that I have following error please look into this:

```
    Sep 27, 2016 6:11:46 PM org.bridj.AbstractBridJRuntime log

SEVERE: Failed to get address of method public static native org.bridj.Pointer org.geotools.data.ogr.bridj.OsrLibrary.OCTProj4Normalize(org.bridj.Pointer)
```